# Add Subversion to XAMPP Apache install

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, httpd

I am trying to get my Apache server restarted after trying to install Subversion.

I have added the following lines to my httpd.conf file for Apache:

```
LoadModule  dav_svn_module         modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule  authz_svn_module       modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

But Apache won't restart and the error log file shows this:

```
C:/xampp/apache/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: The specified module could not be found.
```

That is weird to me because the files were moved there.

```
See the screenshot here: http://screencast.com/t/0FjtHb3isu
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

```
LoadModule dav_module .../mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module .../mod_dav_svn.so
```

Basic DAV module **must** be loaded before svn-specific

Don't forget also about special `Location` container for serving svn-repo (SVN Book have well-written article about running Apache-based repos, BTW)

Answer (score 0):

You are on Windows then .so extensions are no good. You need dll of these libraries.
On the other hand I would recommend using [visual svn](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/), if you are looking for an svn hosting server

Comment: all my other modules are done the same way

Comment: Core modules **are** *.so even in Windows